# Magento Translate is not defined

Tags: magento, translate

I'm getting this error in the site and is messing up my css and some of my js files.

Uncaught ReferenceError: Translate is not defined

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: Can you then post the relevant code?

Comment: @Javi did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

In your page.xml file in the layout directory you are missing the translate.js file

```
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
```